# Returning a new promise reinforced with backup promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm new to promises, so I may be missing something obvious. I'd like a function that takes a list of 'promise creators' as an argument and returns a single promise which either resolves to the first successful promise from the list or rejects to some generic error. This will be used to load data from a website where I have several fallback methods in case one or more methods fail.

Here is a working example of what I mean. There are 3 promises, `m1`, `m2`, and `m3`, which either succeed or fail. `tryAll` will attempt each until one of them (`m3` in this case) resolves which gets passed to the `then` statement of the initial promise request. If `m2` were to resolve instead of `m3`, `m3` is never attempted.

```
function m1(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        reject(new Error("Failed 1"));
    });
}

function m2(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        reject(new Error("Failed 2"));
    });
}

function m3(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        resolve("Succeeded 3");
    });
}

function tryAll(methods){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        if(methods.length == 0){
            reject(new Error("None worked"));
        }else{
            methods[0]()
                .then(function(data){
                    resolve(data);
                })

                .catch(function(err){
                    methods.shift(); // discard the first since it was already tested
                    tryAll(methods)
                        .then(function(data){
                            resolve(data);
                        })

                        .catch(function(err){
                            reject(err);
                        })
                })
        }
    });
}

tryAll([m1, m2, m3])
    .then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    })

    .catch(function(err){
        console.log("failed");
    })
```

Is there any way I can either simplify `tryAll`? Or is there any built-in way for me to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use chaining instead of returning a new promise. For example:

```
function tryAll(methods) {
  if (methods.length === 0) {
    return Promise.reject('None worked');
  }
  return methods[0]().catch(err => tryAll(methods.slice(1)));
}
```

The returned promise of tryAll could be a resolved value from methods[0], or a resolved value of the recursive tryAll call, or a rejection from the tryAll recursion eventually running out of methods.

To demonstrate this iteratively too, you could do something like:

```
function tryAll(methods) {
  return methods.reduce((promise,method) => promise.catch(err => method()), Promise.reject('No methods supplied'));
}
```

This would also return the same chain of promises (although in this case it actually rejects with the last methods error if none fail)

Comment: I did have to change `methods[0]` to `methods[0]()`, but that is significantly better.